# Consider $A(3, 1)$ and $C(4, 3)$. There is a point $B(x, y)$ on the curve $y = x^2$. Minimise $|AB|^2 + |BC|^2$.

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, maxima-minima, coordinate-systems

I took B as $B(x, x^2)$. So far, I tried using the distance formula to get an expression for $|AB|^2 + |BC|^2$. I got $(3 - x)^2 + (1 - x^2)^2 + (x - 4)^2 + (x^2 - 3)^2$. Expanding this out gives $2x^4 - 6x^2 - 14x + 35$. I defined a function $f(x) = 2x^4 - 6x^2 - 14x + 35$. Then, $f'(x) = 8x^3 - 12x - 14$. To get the minimum point of $f(x)$, I tried finding the root of $8x^3 - 12x - 14 = 0$.

$4x^3 - 6x - 7 = 0$, which gives $x = 1.609$ to 4.s.f.

$2(1.609)^4 - 6(1.609)^2 - 14(1.609) + 35 = 10.345324$

I was wondering if there is a way to get an exact answer to this question instead of a decimal.

Comment: Real solutions has cube root involved it. Here is the answer $x = \frac{1}{2} ((7 - \sqrt{41})^{1/3} + (7 + \sqrt{41})^{1/3})$. [General formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#:~:text=on%20the%20circle.-,Solution%20with%20angle%20trisector,it%20has%20three%20real%20roots.)

Comment: Your method and answer seem to be sound, and your question seems to become "how do I find exact roots to a cubic equation where the $x^2$ term is zero?" These are called depressed cubic equations, and the solution was first published by Gerolamo Cardano in the 16th century. That information and google or wikipedia or wolfram alpha should help you find the exact answer.

Comment: I wonder if this problem has a geometrical solution?

Comment: Getting $4x^3 - 6x - 7 = 0$ is enough. I will then try Rational Root Theorem to find rational solution (if any). If there isn't any rational solution then I will definitely use scientific calculator or Wolfram Alpha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to solve this problem without calculus. We can make a system of equations and equate coefficients. We have a family of curves given by

$$
E_{\lambda}(x,y)=(x-x_A)^2+(y-y_A)^2+(x-x_B)^2+(y-y_B)^2=\lambda
$$

and we need to find $\lambda = \lambda^*$ such that $E_{\lambda^*}(x,y)$ and $y-x^2=0$ are tangent. Eliminating $y$ from

$$
\cases{
(x-x_A)^2+(y-y_A)^2+(x-x_B)^2+(y-y_B)^2=\lambda\\
y=x^2
}
$$

we obtain after substitution of $x_A,y_A,x_B,y_B$

$$
2 x^4-6 x^2-14 x+35-\lambda = 0
$$

At tangency we have

$$
2 x^4-6 x^2-14 x+35-\lambda=(x-r)^2(c_0x^2+c_1 x + c_2)
$$

See the double root $r$.

$$
2 x^4-6 x^2-14 x+35-\lambda-(x-r)^2(c_0x^2+c_1 x + c_2)=0 \ \ \forall\ \ x
$$

so we need

$$
\cases{
c_2 r^2+\lambda -35=0\\ 
c_1 r^2-2 c_2 r+14=0\\ 
c_0 r^2-2 c_1 r+c_2+6=0\\
2 c_0r-c_1=0\\
2-c_0=0
}
$$

Now solving for $\lambda, r, c_0,c_1,c_2$ we obtain $\lambda^*=10.3453$. The degree of the involved polynomial (in $r$) entails a numerical solution.